# Injection in Program.cs (.NET Core console app)

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have .NET Core console app and class library

In the class library, I have class, that implements an interface

Here is code of class

```
 public class ServiceThread: IServiceThread
{
    private readonly IServiceWorker _serviceWorker;

    /// <summary>
    /// On service start, Connect to Symphony Cloud to retreive the profile for this device.
    /// Retrieval is done with Mac Address.  
    /// For reference, this operation has been referred to as the "Hello" transaction.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="action">Old logging paramater, soon to be removed.</param>
    public ServiceWorker ServiceWorker;

    private Thread _thread;
    private static Timer _myTimer;

    public ServiceThread(IServiceWorker serviceWorker)
    {
        _serviceWorker = serviceWorker;
    }

    public void Start(string action)
    {
        var myIni = new IniFile();
        Logger.LogAction("IniFile", "Path:" + myIni.pathDir);
        _thread = new Thread(ThreadProc);
        _thread.Start(this);
    }
```

}

I need to call it in Program.cs file

Here is my Program.cs file code

```
class Program
{
    private static IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
    private static IServiceThread ServiceThread { get; }

    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Start!
        //MainAsync(args).Wait();
        // Run with console or service
        var asService = !(Debugger.IsAttached || args.Contains("--console"));

        // var builder = new HostBuilder()
        //     .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) => { services.AddHostedService<MonitoringService>(); });
        // builder.UseEnvironment(asService ? EnvironmentName.Production : EnvironmentName.Development);

        var builder = Host
            .CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, config) => config
                .SetBasePath(Directory.GetParent(AppContext.BaseDirectory).FullName)
                .AddJsonFile("appSettings.json", false))
            .ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
            {
                //services.AddScoped<IHelpersAppService, HelpersAppService>();
                //services.AddSingleton<HelpersAppService>();
                services.AddHostedService<MonitoringService>();
                services.AddSingleton<IHelpersAppService, HelpersAppService>();
                services.AddSingleton<IRestMethods, RestMethods>();
                services.AddSingleton<ISymphonyCloudCommunicator, SymphonyCloudCommunicator>();
                services.AddSingleton<IServiceThread, ServiceThread>();
                services.AddSingleton<IServiceWorker, ServiceWorker>();
                services.AddSingleton<IWsConnector, WsConnector>();
            })
            .UseEnvironment(asService ? EnvironmentName.Production : EnvironmentName.Development);

        if (asService)
        {
            await builder.RunAsServiceAsync();
        }
        else
        {
            ServiceThread.Start("Started");
            await builder.RunConsoleAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

}

I try to it like this `ServiceThread.Start("Started");`

But I get this error on string `ServiceThread.Start("Started");`

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>     at symphony_pc_adapter_netcore.Program.Main(String[] args) in D:\Work\symphony-dotnet-agent\symphony-pc-adapter-netcore\Program.cs:60
>     at at symphony_pc_adapter_netcore.Program.(String[] args)

How I can solve this?

Comment: Well you're never assigning anything to the `ServiceThread` property. How would you expect that to not be null? Perhaps you should be asking the host builder for the `IServiceThread` service? I wouldn't expect anything to arbitrarily set a read-only static property for you though...

Comment: Okay, how I can fix this? @JonSkeet

Comment: As I said before "Perhaps you should be asking the host builder for the IServiceThread service". (There's not much point in configuring the builder to say "here's the IServiceThread implementation" and then ignoring it.)

Comment: I understood, but how? @JonSkeet

Comment: I'd start by thinking about whether it's really appropriate to call `Start` *there* at all rather than after the configuration has been built. But this isn't really the right use of Stack Overflow comment threads. I suggest you read the host builder documentation and think about what you really want to happen. Maybe you should call Build on the builder, for example.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that ServiceThread class is not resolved yet. In order to solve it:

After you are done configuring your builder you should Build() the IHostBuilder, and get a Host object.

```
var builder = Host
                .CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, config) => config
                    .SetBasePath(Directory.GetParent(AppContext.BaseDirectory).FullName)
                    .AddJsonFile("appSettings.json", false))
                .ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
                {
                //services.AddScoped<IHelpersAppService, HelpersAppService>();
                //services.AddSingleton<HelpersAppService>();
                services.AddHostedService<MonitoringService>();
                    services.AddSingleton<IHelpersAppService, HelpersAppService>();
                    services.AddSingleton<IRestMethods, RestMethods>();
                    services.AddSingleton<ISymphonyCloudCommunicator, SymphonyCloudCommunicator>();
                    services.AddSingleton<IServiceThread, ServiceThread>();
                    services.AddSingleton<IServiceWorker, ServiceWorker>();
                    services.AddSingleton<IWsConnector, WsConnector>();
                })
                .UseEnvironment(asService ? EnvironmentName.Production : EnvironmentName.Development);
                var host = builder.Build();
```

Then in your else clause ask for ServiceThread instance and run the start command

```
        else
        {
            var serviceThread = host.Services.GetRequiredService<IServiceThread>();
            serviceThread.Start("NameOfTheAction")
        }
```

Above I have used GetRequiredService(), instead of GetService(), because if the service can not be resolved it will stop execution by throwing an InvalidOperationException.

If you want to get deeper knowledge on the topic I would suggest [Andrew Lock post](https://andrewlock.net/using-dependency-injection-in-a-net-core-console-application/)

Comment: I have now error - Build can only be called once

at this line `await builder.RunConsoleAsync();`

Comment: @EugeneSukh you have this problem because the answer below is wrong. You do not need this line. Check again my answer.

Comment: Oh, sorry, my bad

Comment: But now my app doesn't launch as before and I cannot debug it

It just shows me `(process 27244) exited with code 0.`

Comment: When you run RunConsoleAsync() you request behind the scenes to build the host builder. But your hostbuilder is already built. This is the reason you get the error.

Comment: Okay, so how I can debug my app if debugger not working?

Comment: The debugger does work, the debugger is attached by default when you run your code in visual studio. Did you change the name of the argument the Start() method gets? Put a break point on serviceThread.Start("..."), check if you have a serviceThread instance and step into the method to see what is going on. You just execute the Start() method.

Answer (score -1):

Add the service in you Startup.cs like this:

```
 services.AddSingleton<IServiceThread>();
```

then change you Program.cs

```
                      var builder = Host
                .CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, config) => config
                    .SetBasePath(Directory.GetParent(AppContext.BaseDirectory).FullName)
                    .AddJsonFile("appSettings.json", false))
                .ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
                {
                    //services.AddScoped<IHelpersAppService, HelpersAppService>();
                    //services.AddSingleton<HelpersAppService>();
                    services.AddHostedService<MonitoringService>();
                    services.AddSingleton<IHelpersAppService, HelpersAppService>();
                    services.AddSingleton<IRestMethods, RestMethods>();
                    services.AddSingleton<ISymphonyCloudCommunicator, SymphonyCloudCommunicator>();
                    services.AddSingleton<IServiceThread, ServiceThread>();
                    services.AddSingleton<IServiceWorker, ServiceWorker>();
                    services.AddSingleton<IWsConnector, WsConnector>();
                })
                .UseEnvironment(asService ? EnvironmentName.Production : EnvironmentName.Development);

            if (asService)
            {
                await builder.RunAsServiceAsync();
            }
            else
            {   
using (IServiceScope scope = host.Services.CreateScope())
                {
                    IServiceProvider services = scope.ServiceProvider;
                        ServiceThread serviceThread= services.GetRequiredService<IServiceThread>();
    serviceThread.Start("Started");
     await builder.RunConsoleAsync();
        }

            }
```

Comment: In this solution the build will fail. When you do the builder.RunConsoleAsync() the app tries to build the host builder. But you already have a host in order to resolve your services. So you won't be allowed to build a second one.